# GENConv complains Node and edge feature dimensionalites not matching / assert x[0].size(-1) == edge_attr.size(-1)

Tags: pytorch-geometric

I tried print out the dimension of out[0].shape[-1] and edge_attr.shape[-1], they both as hidden_channels which is 8.

I printed my data, and here is the shape:
Data(x=[253080, 5], edge_index=[2, 100320], edge_attr=[100320, 1], y=[253080, 3], pos=[253080, 3])

class DeeperGCN(torch.nn.Module):

```
def __init__(self, hidden_channels, num_layers):
    super(DeeperGCN, self).__init__()

    self.node_encoder = Linear(5, hidden_channels)
    self.edge_encoder = Linear(1, hidden_channels)

    self.layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
    for i in range(1, num_layers+1):
        conv = GENConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, aggr='softmax',
                       t=1.0, learn_t=True, num_layers=2, norm='layer')
        norm = LayerNorm(hidden_channels, elementwise_affine=True)
        act = LeakyReLU(inplace=True)

        layer = DeepGCNLayer(conv, norm, act, block='res+')
        self.layers.append(layer)
        
    self.conv2 = GENConv(hidden_channels, 3, aggr='softmax',
                       t=1.0, learn_t=True, num_layers=2, norm='layer')

def forward(self, data):
    x, y, edge_index, edge_attr, pos = data.x, data.y, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr, data.pos
    
    out = self.node_encoder(x)
    edge_attr = self.edge_encoder(edge_attr)
    
    for layer in self.layers[1:]:
        out = layer(out, edge_index, edge_attr)
   
    out = self.conv2(out, edge_index, edge_attr)
    
    return out
```